# Assmeby SUBQ and dest registers

Tags: assembly, gdb

So I wrote a code in assembly and I was trying to validate my output with GDB and found a mind puzzling thing!!
So initially:

```
%r15 == 0 and
%rsp == 0x7fffffffe378
```

then

```
#inst src, dest 
movq    %rsp, %r15
%r15 == 0x7fffffffe378 and
%rsp == 0x7fffffffe378
```

then

```
subq    $88, %rsp
%r15 == 0x7fffffffe378 and
%rsp == 0x7fffffffe318   (new value) btw (378_base{16} - 88_base{10} == 320_base{16}!
```

finally

```
subq    $88, %r15
%r15 == 0x7fffffffe320 and    
%rsp == 0x7fffffffe318
```

Shouldn't r15 and rsp be the same?? what are they different by 8? 
What is going on?

SOLVED: 
my original code was:

```
(1) movq    %rsp, %r15
(2) subq    $88, %rsp
(3) pushf
(4) subq    $88, %r15
(5) cmpq    %rsp, %r15
(6) jne notEqual
(7) popf
```

and, of course, the code will always jump to "notEqual" because of the pushf in line 3!

Comment: `%r15` is correct: `$88 -> 0x58` (hex), so I can only assume that something (e.g., a `pushq`?) is changing the `%rsp` value in between.

Comment: thank you @BrettHale. I seems that I forgot about pushf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: my original code was:

```
(1) movq    %rsp, %r15
(2) subq    $88, %rsp
(3) pushf
(4) subq    $88, %r15
(5) cmpq    %rsp, %r15
(6) jne notEqual
(7) popf
```

and, of course, the code will always jump to "notEqual" because of the pushf in line 3!

Comment: You can accept your own answer, to let others know you've resolved the issue.

Comment: @BrettHale I tried but the system is telling me that I have to wait for two days before I could accept it! I guess I'll have to wait..